# Paypal recurring payments not working

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

Today I had created a paypal recurring payment system, i got ack success and profile id. But when in check in my paypal developer account it shows payment start:nov 22, 2014 and next payment due:nov 22, 2014.

Profile is created successfully but amount is not crediting.Need some assistance..

Thanks in advance.

```
$data['AMT'];$data['ACCT'];$data['CREDITCARDTYPE'];   $data['EXPDATE'] ;$data['CVV2'];  $data['FIRSTNAME']    ;     $data['LASTNAME'] ;    $data['STREET'];          $data['CITY'];            $data['STATE'] ;            $data['ZIP'] ;              $data['PROFILESTARTDATE']  ;$data['DESC'] ;            $data['BILLINGPERIOD'];    $data['BILLINGFREQUENCY'];  $data['TOTALBILLINGCYCLES'];$data['TAXAMOUNT'] ;        $data['CURRENCYCODE'];

$api_username               = '*****';
$api_pasword                = '*****';
$api_signature              = '*****';
$api_env                    = PaypalRecurringPaymentProfile::env_type_sandbox;
$api_version                = '75.0';
$pp_profile                 = new PaypalRecurringPaymentProfile($api_username, $api_pasword, $api_signature, $api_version, $api_env);
$pp_create_profile          = $pp_profile->createProfile($data);
```

in create profile fn ($request_param = $data):

```
$result                = $this->paypalHttpPostRequest('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $request_param);
```

in paypalhttp fn:

```
 $nvp_request = "METHOD=" . $method . "&VERSION=" . $this->_api_version . "&PWD=" . $this->_api_password . "&USER=" . $this->_api_username . "&SIGNATURE=" . $this->_api_signature . $nvp_params;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_request);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: are you using any script to make recurring payment?

Comment: yes..from this link http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7423-PHP-Manage-recurring-payments-using-Paypal-API.html i downloaded the package.

Comment: please share the code here

Comment: For recurring payments , it can take up to 24 hrs for the profile to charge.  Usually setting the start date on the same day that the profile is created can charge the profile on the same day but the built in logic is that it can take up to 24 hrs for the charge to complete.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2qlswfr/8      kindly check this image i had done an payment yesterday but it shows active but no payment made to my account

Comment: as you can see that initial payment is $0

Comment: so what should i assign to get it paid??? Sorry im new to paypal